# Android ActionBar Sherlock Icon new intent functionality

Tags: android, android-intent, actionbarsherlock

At the moment i have this code to my actionbar sherlock icons:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // OverFlow PLUS icon ABS
    SubMenu submenu1 = menu.addSubMenu("");
    submenu1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_plus0_transparent);

    submenu1.add(1, 0, 1, "New Cat");
    submenu1.add(1, 1, 2, "New Subcat");
    submenu1.add(1, 2, 3, "Other");
    submenu1.getItem().setShowAsAction(
            MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
                    | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    // OverFlow FILTER icon ABS
    SubMenu submenu2 = menu.addSubMenu("");
    submenu2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_filter0_transparent);

    submenu2.add(1, 0, 1, "Filter 1");
    submenu2.add(1, 1, 2, "Filter 2");
    submenu2.add(1, 2, 3, "Filter 3");
    submenu2.getItem().setShowAsAction(
            MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
                    | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    // OverFlow INFO icon ABS
    SubMenu submenu3 = menu.addSubMenu("");
    submenu3.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_info0_transparent);

    submenu3.add(1, 0, 1, "Info A");
    submenu3.add(1, 1, 2, "Info B");
    submenu3.add(1, 2, 3, "Info C");
    submenu3.getItem().setShowAsAction(
            MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
                    | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    // OverFlow MENU icon ABS
    SubMenu submenu4 = menu.addSubMenu("");
    submenu4.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_menu0_transparent);

    submenu4.add(1, 0, 1, "Primeiro");
    submenu4.add(1, 1, 2, "Segundo");
    submenu4.add(1, 2, 3, "Terceiro");
    submenu4.getItem().setShowAsAction(
            MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
                    | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    // end overflow menu

    return true;
}
```

My intention is for the first icon (submenu1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_plus0_transparent) and second icon (submenu2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_filter0_transparent) to be single clicked buttons that sends the user to other activities and not a dropdown menu. I'm not being able to do that because most part of the examples i've seen had the dropdown menu stuff as the other 2 icons available. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a dropdown because you're using a `submenu`. You should just add it as a normal button instead.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add("whatever")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_plus0_transparent)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

to get click action, do this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getTitle().equals("whatever")) {
         //start your intent here
    }
```

Comment: Hi exception. Thanks. And can you tell me how do i implement the intent in there?